# Workshop Item Sharing Help

Tags: fallout-4

Is it possible for items in workshops to be shared in other workshops? My items have all dissapeared, and yes I have supply lines... They are still in sanctuary, but not showing up in Covenant... PLUS All the wooden floors etc I put away don't transfer over!?

Comment: I think there are two questions here, and while each is a dupe, the two together aren't answered in any one question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two issues.

Items that go into workshops are not available at other settlements except for crafting. You can't just pull them out, but you can use them. For example, you can put duct tape into Sanctuary, and you can use it to make mods in Red Rocket, but you can't pull Duct Tape out of Red Rocket's workshops.

You CAN NOT transfer entities between settlements. If you store a generator in Sanctuary, you can only pull it out at Sanctuary. At Red Rocket, you need to build a new one.

Comment: So basically if I want some stuff back, I need to scrap it all? I understand that would probably be a little complicated to implement, but it`s a little frustrating to say the least! 20+ hours spent in Sanctuary, it buggs out, I move settlement and can't bring what I`ve already built over to the new place? That sucks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but here goes. If what you're asking is "I spent all these resources on stuff in Sanctuary and I want to move to (for example) Covenant, how do I move my stuff," then yes, scraping everything is your best option for improving New Settlement Land. Scraping puts resources directly into the workbench, so if you have a supply line, you'll be able to access it.